# Retrieve item types, their subtype, and counts of those types and subtypes

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, railo, lucee

See below for 1st edit following the answer from @Gordon Linoff

See bottom for 2nd edit/messy solution

**Original question**

I have 3 tables;

```
tblOrganisations
tblOrganisationTypes
tblOrganisationSubTypes
```

An organisation can have a Type, and some Types can have a SubType

I'm trying to get a list and count of Types and SubTypes, but i'm having trouble with the count where a Type has a SubType.

The following query and code;

```
<CFQUERY NAME="RetrieveAllOrganisationTypes" DATASOURCE="#strDev#">
    SELECT tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID , COUNT(tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID) AS TypeCount , COUNT(tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID) AS SubTypeCount , tblOrganisationTypes.OrganisationType , tblOrganisationSubTypes.OrganisationSubType
            FROM (( tblOrganisations
            LEFT JOIN tblOrganisationTypes ON tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID = tblOrganisationTypes.ReferenceID )
            LEFT JOIN tblOrganisationSubTypes ON tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID = tblOrganisationSubTypes.ReferenceID )
            GROUP BY tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID , tblOrganisations.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID
            ORDER BY tblOrganisationTypes.OrganisationType , tblOrganisationSubTypes.OrganisationSubType
</CFQUERY>

<CFOUTPUT QUERY="RetrieveAllOrganisationTypes" GROUP="OrganisationType">
    #OrganisationType# (#TypeCount#)<BR>
    <CFIF OrganisationSubType IS NOT ""><CFOUTPUT GROUP="OrganisationSubType">-- #OrganisationSubType# (#SubTypeCount#)<BR></CFOUTPUT></CFIF>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

Gets me this;

```
AFFILIATED (2)
ASSOCIATE (15)
FULL (10)
-- operator (10)
-- manufacturer (4)
-- owner (108)
-- survey company (4)
-- supplier (4)
GOVERNMENT (5)
MISCELLANEOUS (3)
SCIENCE (4)
```

But you see, the Full count - 10 - is wrong. It should be 130! For Types without a SubType the count is correct. The SubTypes count is correct. I've tried all sorts but i'm not getting anywhere :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

**1st edit**

Following the help from @Gordon Linoff, adding the WITH ROLLUP, removing the ORDER BY, and with the following code;

```
<CFOUTPUT QUERY="RetrieveAllOrganisationTypes" GROUP="OrganisationType">
    #OrganisationType# (#TypeCount#) #SubTypeCount#<BR>
    <CFIF OrganisationSubType IS NOT ""><CFOUTPUT GROUP="OrganisationSubType">-- #OrganisationSubType# (#TypeCount#) #SubTypeCount#<BR></CFOUTPUT></CFIF>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

I now get;

```
AFFILIATED (2) 2
ASSOCIATE (15) 15
FULL (10) 10
-- operator (10) 10
-- manufacturer (4) 4
-- owner (108) 108
-- survey company (4) 4
-- supplier (4) 4
-- (130) 130
GOVERNMENT (5) 5
MISCELLANEOUS (3) 3
SCIENCE (4) 4
(159) 159
```

So you see i am getting the 130, but how do i get the 130 by the FULL?!

**2nd edit/messy solution**

So i guess this is a kinda messy solution, but it works!

The following output code;

```
<CFOUTPUT QUERY="RetrieveAllOrganisationTypes" GROUP="OrganisationType">
    <CFOUTPUT GROUP="OrganisationSubType">
    <CFIF OrganisationSubType IS "" AND OrganisationType IS NOT "">#OrganisationType# (#TypeCount#)<BR></CFIF>
    </CFOUTPUT>
    <CFOUTPUT GROUP="OrganisationSubType">
    <CFIF OrganisationSubType IS NOT "" AND OrganisationType IS NOT "">--#OrganisationSubType# (#SubTypeCount#)<BR></CFIF>
    </CFOUTPUT>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

Gives me;

```
AFFILIATED (2)
ASSOCIATE (15)
FULL (130)
--operator (10)
--manufacturer (4)
--owner (108)
--survey company (4)
--supplier (4)
GOVERNMENT (5)
MISCELLANEOUS (3)
SCIENCE (4)
```

I'm sure there is probably a cleaner way to do this, and if anyone knows it i'm open to suggestions, but for now - this is working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query with table aliases so it is a bit easier to read:

```
SELECT o.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID ,     
       COUNT(o.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID) AS TypeCount , 
       COUNT(o.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID) AS SubTypeCount , 
       ot.OrganisationType , ost.OrganisationSubType
FROM tblOrganisations o LEFT JOIN
     tblOrganisationTypes ot
     ON o.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID = ot.ReferenceID LEFT JOIN
     tblOrganisationSubTypes ost
     ON o.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID = ost.ReferenceID )
GROUP BY o.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID, 
         o.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID
ORDER BY ot.OrganisationType , ost.OrganisationSubType;
```

You are confused.  The "10" that you are getting is the number of organizations with `FULL` that have no subtypes.  It is not some sort of aggregation.  If you want sums at different levels, then a good approach uses `ROLLUP`:

```
GROUP BY o.tblOrganisationTypes_ReferenceID, 
         o.tblOrganisationSubTypes_ReferenceID WITH ROLLUP
```

This is going to produce additional rows for *all* possible subtotals (including a total for the whole table).  You will need to figure out how to filter the resulting rows to get what you want.  You should review the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) on this feature.

Comment: thanks for your help, i'd never heard of WITH ROLLUP - so i will look into it. i tried the WITH ROLLUP but i got an error - "Error Executing Database Query. Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY" but i found if i removed the ORDER BY stuff , it works - the counts are all good :)

Comment: ahhhh ... from that link to the documentation; 'When you use ROLLUP, you cannot also use an ORDER BY clause to sort the results. In other words, ROLLUP and ORDER BY are mutually exclusive. '

Comment: sorry i was wrong :( the count isn't correct - i'm getting; ASSOCIATE (15)
FULL (108)
-- owner (108)
-- operator (10)
-- manufacturer (4)
-- system supplier (4)
-- survey company (4)
GOVERNMENT (5)
SCIENCE (4)
AFFILIATED (2)
MISCELLANEOUS (3)

Comment: thanks again, i've marked this as the answer as the WITH ROLLUP was key, and you did say i'd have to figure out how to get what i wanted with the results :)